# how to print an object containing multiple arrays inside a same element in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, iteration

so here is an object

```
{
  can: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
  votes: [12, 21, 30, 25]
}
```

and I want the result to be like this

candidate name    vote-count

candidatte name  vote-count

I tried different combinations of Object.keys() and Object.enttries() but none worked for me. it always gives

candidate name candidate name

vote-count vote-count

stackoverflow gave me duplicate but they all contain an array inside the main object. here I have values inside the object.

Comment: If you want to do the following, 

`[ { candidate: "a", vote: 12 }, { candidate: "b", vote: 21 }, { candidate: "c", vote: 30 }, { candidate: "d", vote: 25 } ]`

then try this.

`const data = { can: ["a", "b", "c", "d"], votes: [12, 21, 30, 25] }`
`const { can, votes } = data`
`const newData = can.map((value, index) => ({ candidate: value, vote: votes[index] }))`